# MapboxGeocoding returning invalid lat and long (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm basically trying to get Lat and Long from entered address, but the MapboxGeocoding method returns invalid co ordinates which does not range between -90 to 90.

```
MapboxGeocoding mapboxGeocoding = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
                .accessToken(getString(R.string.access_token))
                .query("50 Beale St, San Francisco, CA")
                .build();

        Log.d(TAG, "THe mapbox geocode: " + mapboxGeocoding.toString());

        mapboxGeocoding.enqueueCall(new Callback<GeocodingResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Response<GeocodingResponse> response) {

                if (response.body() != null) {


                    List<CarmenFeature> results = response.body().features();
                    Log.d(TAG, "carmen response : " + results.toString());

                    if (results.size() > 0) {

                        // Log the first results Point.
                        Point firstResultPoint = results.get(0).center();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Lat : " + firstResultPoint.longitude());
                        Log.d(TAG, "long : " + firstResultPoint.latitude());

                        mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                                new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                        .target(new LatLng(firstResultPoint.longitude(), firstResultPoint.latitude()))
                                        .zoom(17)
                                        .build()), 4000);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + firstResultPoint.toString());

                    } else {

                        // No result for your request were found.
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: No result found");

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Nothing found");
                }
            }
```

This part here :

```
       MapboxGeocoding mapboxGeocoding = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
                .accessToken(getString(R.string.access_token))
                .query("50 Beale St, San Francisco, CA")
                .build();
```

returns co ordinates of :

```
Lat : -122.396457
long : 37.791239
```

Which are completely wrong, my log:

```
12-04 10:52:21.531 11351-11351/io.apptizer.business.clover E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.apptizer.business.clover, PID: 11351
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: latitude must be between -90 and 90
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng.setLatitude(LatLng.java:132)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng.<init>(LatLng.java:67)
        at io.apptizer.pos.activity.SearchLocationActivity$2.onResponse(SearchLocationActivity.java:222)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why is this happening, is it because I'm using a public mapbox key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe

```
.target(new LatLng(firstResultPoint.longitude(), firstResultPoint.latitude()))
```

should be

```
.target(new LatLng(firstResultPoint.latitude(), firstResultPoint.longitude()))
```

as the name LatLng suggests.

Comment: Hey man i recently posten a new question, could u help me with it. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139756/setting-carmen-feature-address-to-my-address-object-mapbox-android    @Anatoly Sukhanov